# Get the names of the folders which are shared as "Everyone" in the current system

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How to get the names and location of the folders which are created with "Everyone" privilage 
in a current system

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410127/c-sharp-test-if-user-has-write-access-to-a-folder). You should be able to implement that for your own needs.

Comment: `icacls c:\ /findsid everyone /T` and then capture the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1h6d4k4.aspx)  to get

> Gets a DirectorySecurity object that encapsulates the access control
>   list (ACL) entries for the directory described by the current
>   DirectoryInfo object.

for a single directory in system. The rest is a matter of implementation of iteratiing over all dircetories in the system and calling this.

Example:

```
    string[] drives = System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
    foreach (string dr in drives)
    {
        System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dr);


        if (!di.IsReady)
        {               
            continue;
        }
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo root = di.RootDirectory;
        var directories = root.GetDirectories("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach(var dirInfo in directories ) {
            var diAccess = dirInfo.GetAccessControl(..) ;
        }

    }
```

Complete example and explanation can find: [How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx)

This is just a sketch, change it to fit your needs.