# Directory.Exist : identify types of errors

Tags: c#

I use `Directory.Exist` to test a directory, but I can not distinguish types of errors.
I would like to distinguish if the directory doesn't exist or access is not allowed.  I saw this link [C# Test if user has write access to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410127/c-sharp-test-if-user-has-write-access-to-a-folder) but it's quite long and complicated.   There is not an easier way?

Comment: It's 5 lines of actual code, hardly "long".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Exist` method to check whether the directory exists or not. Like this

```
if(Directory.Exists(directory)) {
  // directory exists
  try
    {
      // and is accessible by user...
      File.GetAccessControl(filePath);
      return true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
      // but is unable to be accessed...
      return false;
    }
} else {
  // directory doesn't exist, so no file accessible.
}
```

This is a bit easy and understand code for you. Each of the method is having its own commentary for you.