# How to check for directory write permission in .NET when 'Controlled folder access' ON

Tags: c#, controlled-folder-access

When trying to create folder in My Documents with 'Controlled folder access' ON CreateFolder throws FileNotFoundException. 
I need to check if my app can create folder in My Documents. How I can check that I have permission for it when 'Controlled folder access' ON.

I tried DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl method for it, it shows that it allows. Is only way now for me to try create a folder and handle FileNotFoundException.

```
try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(MyDocuments, "Foo"));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: it looks like this link might help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410127/c-sharp-test-if-user-has-write-access-to-a-folder) and [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135982/get-directory-permissions-for-all-directories-in-tree)

Comment: @PowerMouse I saw this links, they suggest to use **DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl**, unfortunately it shows that I have Full Access

Comment: AFAIK this is strictly a User setting. 
you can give permissions per application IMHO.
[windows-10-allow-blocked-app-windows-security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046851/windows-10-allow-blocked-app-windows-security)

Comment: @PowerMouse yes, this is a user setting. I want to show instructions to the end-user of how to add it, but before it I need to know whether the reason is 'Controlled folder access' or not. Maybe there is any WinApi flag for it or etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileNotFoundException` is certainly unexpected here as `Directory.CreateDirectory` does not have it in the list of [documented exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.8). This exception seems to be the result of Windows Defender blocking your app from accessing the folder and not the Windows File System which is on the lower level and hence the `System.IO` is giving you a successful result.

Check this [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26561) as it seems to be your situation. And the very [last comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26561#issuecomment-367867084) is suggesting to allow the app via Controlled access list. I suspect until the proper exception type is implemented low level you are pretty much stuck catching the undocumented exception here. There might be some undocumented WinAPI to ask the Windows Defender if your app has access to the folder, but relying on it might be more error prone in the long run. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but I need it for a desktop application, so I cannot change the access list on the user's computer.

Comment: Misreporting is certainly a bug downstream. However, considering the uniqueness of the bug I'd say you may consider relying on the misreporting as your condition and give the end-user instructions of how to add your app to the list if it happens. Make sure you handle the documented exceptions in another catch to handle the negative scenarios too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this is by checking a couple of things.

1. Check whether Controlled folder access is enabled on the computer
2. If it is enabled then check to see if your application has been exempted from the control.

This is done by checking the local machine registry key:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Exploit
>   Guard\Controlled Folder Access

1. Read the value for `EnableControlledFolderAccess` (1 is enabled 0 for disabled) - *note that this can also be nothing!*
2. Loop through the `SubKeyNames` then `GetValueNames()` for the key `AllowedApplications` - *(returns a string array)*

If Controlled Folder Access is enabled and your application name (`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.Name`) is not in the AllowedApplications list, then you'll get the `FileNotFoundException` and won't be able to create the folder (the user will also get a virus warning!).

**EDIT:**

There is also another subkey under that hive, `ProtectedFolders` which lists the default folders that Microsoft have decided need to be protected (and include folders such as My Documents, My Pictures etc) plus any others that the user (administrator) may add. You could also check this (string array) if Controlled Folder Access is enabled on the system.