# How to operate two command in c#?

Tags: c#

```
class testapplication
{
    static void ProcessString(string s)
    {

        {
        Directory.Move("@C:/Users/Public/TestFolder", "@C:/Users/Public/TestFolder1");<1
        Directory.Move("@C:/Users/Public/TestCase", "@C:/Users/Public/TestCase1");<2
        }
    }
}
```

For a example like this  case, it can only run 1  and 2 cannot active.

[image]

Comment: Add it in try catch block and check if it throwing any exception on first call.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run them in parallel?

Comment: You're moving two same directories, of course it won't work once you move the first directory, the directory is gone

Comment: I am sorry! the question should be wrong and now is updated!

Comment: First you should give a valid path: `"@C:/Users/Public/TestFolder"` should be `@"C:/Users/Public/TestFolder"`; Place `@` outside the `"`

Comment: What are the `<1` and `<2` at the end of the lines?????

Comment: <1 means first command and <2  is second command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `[Directory.Move Method (String, String)][1]` Moves a file or a
>   directory and its contents to a new location.

So at the time of execution of the second command the source becomes empty. if you need to take a copy of testFolder, as testfolder1 and testFolder2 and remove the testfolder, i prefer you to do a copy first and then perform move

```
try
 { 
  Directory.Copy(@"c:/Users/Public/TestFolder", @"c:/Users/Public/TestFolder1",true);// will take a copy of the directory TestFolder1
  Directory.Move(@"c:/Users/Public/TestCase", @"c:/Users/Public/TestCase1");//will move TestFolder to TestFolder2
 }
catch{//handle exception here}
```

Comment: Find out a new problem and  with picture! Can you tell me what wrong in this case? :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code depicts a move operation which will cause an error in the second line.. a copy operation will be successful :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that should check accessible for source folder before move it.

See [check Check if directory is accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709862/check-if-directory-is-accessible-in-c)

I just test on my computer. It works fine with following code

```
if(CanRead(@"C:/Users/hai2/Desktop"))  
   Directory.Move(@"C:/Users/hai2/Desktop", @"C:/Users/hai2/Desktop1");// command 1
if(CanRead(@"C:/Users/hai2/Links"))  
   Directory.Move(@"C:/Users/hai2/Links", @"C:/Users/hai2/Links1");//command 2
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Find out a new problem and with picture! Can you tell me what wrong in this case?

Comment: you should "Check if directory is accessible" before you move it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute two operations at the same time, then you can start them in two separate threads. The best way to do this is to use `Task` functionality.

```
var move1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Directory.Move("@C:/Users/Public/TestFolder", "@C:/Users/Public/TestFolder1"));
var move2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Directory.Move("@C:/Users/Public/TestCase", "@C:/Users/Public/TestCase1"));

Task.WaitAll(move1, move2); // will wait until work is done
```

It will make start two asynchronous `Directory.Move` operations, and will continue only when both of them will be finished.

Comment: Find out a new problem and with picture! Can you tell me what wrong in this case?

Comment: @Fabre Make sure that this directory has no files, which are now open in other applications or busy. You cannot move such directories.