# How to check for read permissions on a folder?

Tags: c#, directory

I know that this method is good to check if a user has write permissions to folder:

```
Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
```

If it throws `UnauthorizedAccessException` I know that the user has read permission or non permission.

How to know if a user has read permissions?

Is `Directory.Exists(path)` a good enough solution?

Comment: Please check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709862/check-if-directory-is-accessible-in-c

Comment: Directory.GetAccessControl(path) will throw exception in the user hasn't write permissions.

Comment: @programmer117 's solution is the best possible as I think - you should suggest making it a small seperate answer cause I think this is not trivial, or just Close the issue ;)
BTW: "According to MSDN, Directory.Exists should return false if you don't have read access to the Directory" - so yes to your original question, the problem will be you can't be sure if the folder does even exists by just checking it like this

Comment: According to official documentation, Directory.GetAccessControl(path) will throw exception if user doesn't have write permissions to folder, so it isn't looks like a good solution to test read permissions