# How to check Read and write permissions on folder in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my website i want to create a new folder and then copy some files in it and also i want to create an `html` file through `C#` code. I want to know

1. How to check read and write permission on a folder
2. How to create an html file on runtime in project root

Im using `Asp.net MVC 2` and `C#`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How to check read and write permission on a folder

```
string folder = ...

var permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, folder);
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissionSet.AddPermission(permission);
if (permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
{
    // You have write permission for the given folder
}
```

> How to create an html file on runtime in project root

```
string file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), "foo.html");
File.WriteAllText(file, "<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use App_Data where the identity of ASP.NET application automatically has read and write permissions?

Comment: How can I check it for .Net 3.5 SP1? I have got error:
`'System.AppDomain' does not contain a definition for 'PermissionSet' and no extension method 'PermissionSet' accepting a first argument of type 'System.AppDomain' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

Comment: app_data doesn't have write permission by default for hosted apps