# asp.net Forms Authentication restrict access to folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure

I have a website contains following structure, it will be deploy to Azure Web App:

```
~\Home\Files\(kk.jpg) (ff.pdf) (aa.xls)....
~\Home\Download.aspx
~\LogIn.aspx
~\Web.config
```

Rules:

1. Only login users can see anything in the "Home" directory.
2. Especially, I want to restrict any un-login users access any file in the "\Home\Files\" directory.

Here is my web.config file:

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".SCKi" loginUrl="LogIn.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" requireSSL="true"  />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users ="?" />
      <allow users = "*" />
     </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Can any one help me apply the rules?

Comment: have you checked permissions to that folder ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396913/how-to-check-read-and-write-permissions-on-folder-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock access on specific folders using `location` tag in web.config.

```
<location path="Home/Files">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This will come under `configuration` tag

Comment: The question is when I deploy it to the server, if I enter the path say "www.mywebsite/Home/Files/Test1.txt" in the browser, I can still see the txt file in the browser, without log in.

Comment: Yes you will have to write this in web.config to restrict users without login.

Comment: I put it in there like this, but still can access `<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".SCKi" loginUrl="LogIn.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" requireSSL="true"  />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users ="?" />
      <allow users = "*" />
     </authorization>
</system.web><location path="Home/Files">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>'

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing everyone in:

Change to this:

```
<allow users="?" />
```

E remove the deny option