# Is there a safe way of detecting File access permissions

Tags: c#, vb.net, file-io

Below is the part code I currently use to write to a file,

```
Try
    Using sWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Tmp.txt", False)
        sWriter.Write(m_Buffer.ToString) : sWriter.Flush()
    End Using
        Return True
Catch ex As IOException

End Try
```

but some time this results in error

```
Access to the path 'C:\Tmp.txt' is denied
```

My question is, Is there a safe way of detecting File access permissions, without handling exceptions, I mean if I can some how check before opening a file for any filehandle opened for it.

I think I have made my point. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use FileInfo class to check on the permissions of the file. But again, if some other process is using the file, that also could cost you an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been other similar questions asked in **StackoverFlow**. 
check this before you ask!

[How do you check for permissions to write to a directory or file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130617/how-do-you-check-for-permissions-to-write-to-a-directory-or-file)
[how can you easily check if access is denied for a file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net)

The first link can help you directly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's possible for a file to become locked *after* a hypothetical call to an `IsFileLocked()` method, you are always going to want exception handling around your subsequent I/O operation.

Such code would like like what you have now.

Comment: Yep! Exception Handling would remain there I was just looking for the way to get out of procedure if the file is being used.