# image upload in file system on server in asp.net3 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to upload image and store it in file system in asp.net using c#.
i am using this code

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if ((FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg") ||
           (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png") ||
           (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/tmp") ||
           (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/gif"))
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt64(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength) < 10000000)
            {
                string filename = Label1.Text;
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("productImage\\" + ddlproductId.Text + "\\" + filename + ".jpg"));

            }
        }
    }
```

it actually work fine in my computer but while i am uploading it on server it get some error. please help me. thanking you.

Comment: "get some error" -- *what* error?

Comment: Access to the path 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\bcharyacorporation.com\httpdocs\productImage\101\1.jpg' is denied.  this is the error.. @hometoast

Comment: There you go. Whatever user the IIS service is running as doesn't have write access to create those files.

Comment: can you tell me the solution @hometoast

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a permissions problem. You'll want to change the security of that folder on the web server and ensure `NETWORK SERVICE` has `Write` permissions. Or, if you have an older server, it will be `ASPNET`.

Comment: That should work with default settings.  If the IIS settings have been changed you should check to see what user it runs as.  If you are using an AppPool it will be the user the AppPool runs as that you need to give permissions.

Comment: can you please tell me where can i change the file permission to write

Comment: You can navigate to it in Windows Explorer, Right click folder -> Properties -> Security.

Comment: how can i do it in server @MikeSmithDev

Comment: What do you mean "in server"? I was referring to when you are logged into the server and then go run Windows Explorer and navigate to the folder.

Comment: Perhaps this will help if you are looking for code solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130617/how-do-you-check-for-permissions-to-write-to-a-directory-or-file