# Exception raised on special folder in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, directory, authorization

In my application I use the following command to get all files from a selected path:

```
foreach (string currentFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    //some logic here
}
```

The thing is that when trying to access certain directories such as `c:\Documents and Settings` I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

The folder mentioned above doesn't show in `Windows Explorer` or in the `.NET System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` and i can't find a specific attribute of this folder so I could filter the enumeration by.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130617/how-do-you-check-for-permissions-to-write-to-a-directory-or-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net) but with no use.

Is there any kind of attribute or parameter I can use to restrict this kind of directories from my loop?

Comment: Windows Explorer simply doesn't list "Documents and Settings" because it's marked as a hidden system folder. It doesn't care whether it's accessible, if you configure Explorer to show hidden and system files and folders, it'll show up, but it'll still be inaccessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directory class does not provide a means to skip over inaccessible files and folders. You can write your own directory scanning method, that will recursively go into each folder and skip it if exception occurs.

Comment: There's no way to check for this by checking the `DirectoryInfo` parameters?

Comment: You can get access control list using DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl() and then try to figure out if you have the permissions. But I see no reason for doing it, as catching exception would be easier to implement and understand.

Comment: Ended up with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/929418/1092181, apparently (and surprisingly) it is easier to catch the `exception` rather than checking for permissions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get a Sys Admin to give your user read permissions to all the files? Sounds like there are things you can't access. Though I don't discourage you from solving this issue by excluding these files just from a portability standpoint(I can't speak directly to how to do this unfortunately).

Comment: I don't want to access unauthorized directories. I just want to skip them.

Comment: Our security officer would have a heart attack if he read this answer.