# How do I check whether the application has permission to delete a file or directory on disk, by using PermissionSet property?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to determine, whether an application is allowed to delete a file or directory on file system. For that purpose I currently use the approach, decribed in

[How do you check for permissions to write to a directory or file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462329/1817029). 
(I it for both, files and directories)

Unfortunately, the ***SecurityManager.IsGranted Method*** is marked as obsolete. [http://msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitymanager.isgranted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

How can I do this check by using the suggested `PermissionSet property`?

Comment: Check the folder has IUSR and NETWORK SERVICES (read,write and execute) permission

Comment: @DavidArno Thanks for your comment. The `SecurityManager.Demand()` seems to be the right way. But way do *msdn.microsoft.com* suggest to use the `PermissionSet` instead. Are there any differences? And why do they call a method for checking the permission `Demand()`???
... microsoft :(

Comment: @RajasekarGunasekaran Can you please provide a short sample of that?

Comment: You need to check folder permission in folder property,http://www.uwec.edu/Help/drives/permissions.htm