# How do I revoke write permission from a file so that it can't be deleted in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions

Within a NUnit test I need to check whether an existing file can be deleted or not. The UnitUnderTest source looks like:

```
public static Boolean IsWritePermissionGranted(String absoluteFilePath)
{
    Boolean isGranted = true;
    try
    {
        FileIOPermission writePermission = new FileIOPermission(
            FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, absoluteFilePath);
        writePermission.Demand();
    }
    catch (SystemException)
    {
        isGranted = false;
    }
    return isGranted;
}
```

Within the test case I want to revoke the write permission from the TestFile. So far I tried:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590491/1817029
2. `AddFileSecurity(TEST_FILE_PATH, @"MyDomain\MyUser", FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Deny);`
3. `DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(TEST_FILE_PATH);

   DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
   dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
     TEST_FILE_PATH, "MyDomain\MyUser", FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Deny));
   dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);`

In all cases the file can still be deleted. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and quickest way of preventing *accidental* deletion is just to make it read-only:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Any code that wishes to modify or delete this file will have to explicitly remove the read-only attribute first (i.e. with another call to `SetAttributes`).

You should also **never** catch `SystemException` (or `Exception` for that matter), and anyway your example code is dealing with CAS which has nothing to do with file security.

Comment: Thank you! *[... and anyway your example code is dealing with CAS which has nothing to do with file security.]* Do you refer to `writePermission.Demand();` Further, I can still delete the file with: `File.Delete(TEST_FILE_PATH);`

Comment: Yes. If you look up the [documentation for the Demand method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.codeaccesspermission.demand(v=vs.110).aspx), you should see that it clearly doesn't apply to your scenario in any way. There is in fact no reliable way to test whether or not a file can be deleted other than to actually attempt to delete it and catch the `IOException` or `SecurityException` if it fails. Your test is checking for a totally unrelated kind of permission, and will always return true when running under full trust. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1444153/38360)

Comment: I got this as a solution (just as an comment) to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19860927/1817029 
I asked this question since the `SecurityManager.IsGranted` method is marked as obsolete. Can you please answer that question? 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/19860927/1817029

THX!

Comment: That question is closed. There are many duplicates, but the best one is probably the one I linked to in my last comment.